# Accidentally deleted windows event logs, what is file extension?

Tags: windows, logging, file-recovery, events

Hey I accidentally deleted windows logs I needed but I havent wrote anything to the disk and I have a third party file restore program so I was wondering if anyboddy knew the file extension of windows event logs if it was .doc or .log I can't seem to find what it is with google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover or "undelete" files that I accidentally deleted?](http://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
C:\Windows\System32\config
```

In this location, they could be `.log, .log1, .log2` or no extension.

This is what it looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: Not when you accidentally deleted them, well my system is the equivelent of cooked now because I needed those to fix one hell of a error, thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: Those aren't the event logs, they are the registry transaction logs.

Comment: I never said they were event logs...

Answer (score 4):

In Windows XP, event logs have extension `.evt` and are in

```
windows\system32\config
```

In Windows 7, event logs have extension `.evtx` and are in

```
windows\system32\winevt\Logs
```

I believe Windows Vista and Windows 8 are both the same as Windows 7, but I don't have a box handy to check.

Comment: In Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise also is windows\system32\winevt\Logs

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez: yeah, Windows Server 2008 R2 is just the server version of Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the possibility to find what you are looking for, I suggest to look for

- `.evt` files
- `.txt` files
- `.log` files