# Corrupted document files with a strange extension

Tags: windows-7, file-extension, file-corruption

Today I turned no my PC and I faced an strange problem. Most of my documents and files such as .jpg, .pptx, .docx, .pdf where renamed with for example "xxxxxx.JPG.dslttdk" and "xxxx.PDF.dslttdk" and so on. I rename files and remove .dslttdk extension, but the contents are unknown yet. If I open them with Notepad, the contents are replaced with some strange characters like japanese characters.
I have an updated antivirus, and I do not know how this problem has been appeared. Please help me with this corrupted  .dslttdk! extension files.

Comment: I will start with the docx file, and if it works comment and I will move on to the .jpg, pptx and .pdf files. docx documents are zipped XML files. The document.xml file in the word folder of the .zip archive contains the document's text. For how to recover a corrupted .docx file try this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/957392/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-docx-file/957558#957558

Comment: Are they renamed, or are these different files with the same name as existing files?  If you rename xxxx.jpg.dslttdk back to xxxxx.jpg does it open?

Comment: @Paul. Files size are the same. The size is different from 2 MB to 300 MB. When I rename them back, they do not open.

Comment: @karel. I uploaded a .docx document on Google Drive. But it showed file corruption error when I opened it: "Sorry, an error occurred when opening this file. Please try again."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: If it is Ransomware it cannot be reversed, and removal of the ransomware will remove the opportunity to purchase back their files if need be.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have been hit by ransomware: malware that encrypts your files, requiring you to send a payment to hackers to obtain the decryption key.  You probably need to reinstall your operating system and restore your data from backups.  (You do have backups, don't you?)

Comment: They should stop using the PC and copy off all data to an external drive immediately. The encryption ransomware may be in progress and may have not encrypted all files yet.