# How to recover .json files on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, data-recovery, json

Ich have accidently formatted a hard drive, where my Firefox bookmarks were. They are in .json format. I have tried software like Recuva,Magic Partition Recovery, PC Inspector File Recovery, R-Studio 6.3, EASEUS Data Recovery Wizard. No success. I can find old photos or some other old stuff, but not the json files.

Comment: My first result in Google may help http://www.finalseeker.com/recover-firefox-bookmarks.html

Comment: It sounds like you have already overwritten the sectors the json files were located at. If this happen then the files cannot be recovered.  These files are not special.  If `Recuva` didn't work then `Finalseeker Data Recovery` won't work.

Comment: @DaveRook I've tested it finds nothing.

Comment: @Ramhound I did only a quick formatting. I did no other action and I can find other files, except json

Comment: @user220542 - I am just telling you the facts.  There is nothing special about the .json files they are simple text files.  If you cannot locate the files with recovery software then the files are likely gone overwritten by new data.  If you didn't run recovery software right away, placed new data on the formatted drive, degragged the free space all of that could have caused the files to be unrecoverable.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/423134/recover-files-deleted-from-windows-7-with-no-backup. That question was about recovering files that were simply deleted. This question is similar, but about a hard disk that was re-formatted.

Comment: @KevinFegan: There are a whole bunch of questions about data recovery after a quick/full format. I'm sure we can find other questions to close this as a duplicate of if you want. :)